# MeioUpload and phpThumb() does not exist error

Tags: php, cakephp, phpthumb, cakephp-2.2, meio-upload

I am currently using CakePHP v2.2.1 and MeioUpload 4.0 along with phpThumb() to try and generate image uploads and thumbnails for those images. If i set my `$actAs = array()` without the thumbsizes property everything is uploaded well, but when I add the following:

```
'thumbsizes' => array(
    'small' => array('width' => 165, 'height' => 115),
    'medium' => array('width' => 800, 'height' => 600)
),
```

to generate thumbnails I get an error stating the following:

```
"E:/xampp/htdocs/site/vendors/phpthumb/img/posts/image-name.jpg" does not exist
```

I have tried several different methods of fixing this from around the web and nothing seems to work. I am new to cakephp so this may be an easy fix and I am just not connecting the dots to find the solution. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Put answer below this comment...

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with Miles J. plugin found here [milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader). Seems that Meio's has an issue with the 2.2.1 version of CakePHP all is good again!